# Can't find a Wordpress image/photo gallery plugin

Tags: php, image, wordpress, plugins, gallery

I've been looking at Wordpress plugins for photo galleries (so maybe this is for superuser.com), and I've been very frustrated so far.  It seems like what I'd like to do would be a very common use case:

- Admin: Be able to upload multiple pictures (at a time)
- Admin: Be able to assign a "gallery" to those pictures as I upload them
- User: Be able to go to a page with a (paged) list of all galleries
- User: Be able to click on gallery and view the images (again, probably paged) in that gallery
- User: Be able to click on an image to get larger/largest sizes
- User: Be able to leave comments on individual pictures (this is a "nice to have")

The images/galleries could be totally independent of posts/pages, but it would be nice to be able to embed those images/galleries into posts/pages when necessary.

Is there anything out there like this that I'm missing?  I've tried a handful of plugins and none of them seem to be for a use case anywhere close to what I'm looking for.  One of the reasons I'm trying to use Wordpress is to reduce time spent coding everything I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [NextGen Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/). It's a great image gallery plugin for WordPress.

Try taking a look at the this [NextGen site](http://nextgen-gallery.com/) for a walkthrough of all it's features.

Comment: I tried that one, and could not get it to work like I want for the life of me!

Comment: What sort of problems did you have? That's the best plugin for this type of solution to my knowledge.

Comment: Well, some parts just didn't seem to work right.  I have no idea what an 'album' is, and how it works, and why it's different from a 'gallery', and there didn't seem to be any way to see a list of all galleries as a public user.

Comment: An album is a collection of galleries. e.g. an album named "Restaurants", which contains a collection of galleries and each gallery is specific to a restaurant. What are some of the other challenges you're facing with NextGen?

Comment: So, what I really need is one "album" with all my galleries.  How do I set up a wordpress page to list albums?

Comment: If you create one album to house ALL of your galleries you simply edit the post/page you want to include the album in and use the TinyMCE that NextGen installs on the visual editor to drop in the album. It should then give you a list of all the galleries. There's a few different configurations to how it will display the album/galleries, so you may have to play with it a bit. I also @'ed you on Twitter.

Comment: Okay doke, I will give it another go, and bother you on Twitter if I can't get it working.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other alternatives that look like they may fit what you're looking for (of course, you may have already tried them unsuccessfully):

[PhotoSmash Galleries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photosmash-galleries/)

[Post videos and photo galleries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-rich-videos-and-photos-galleries/)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Tag Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tag-gallery/) may be of interest to you. You can manage your media via tags from the built in Media Library of Wordpress and this plugin builds galleries from your tags. Pretty nifty.

Comment: # . : **404** : . # . : **Dead link** : . #